# Dynamically assigned Ajax URL string doesn't show anything on jquery-ui Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, autocomplete

I have a problem with AJAX url. I am trying to get autocomplete data using AJAX, and AJAX url I assign dynamically. But it doesn't work, although if I put static AJAX url string it works perfectly fine. Help me please. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>TEST Window</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/jquery-ui.css')}}">

    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action ="{{route('testbtn')}}" method='POST' accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="col-md-1" >Profession </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Select profession" class="ui-widget form-control autocomplete" name="f1" id="f1" value="" data-href="{{URL::to('searchp')}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1" >Region</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Select a region" class="ui-widget form-control autocomplete" name="f2" id="f2" value="" data-href="{{URL::to('searchr')}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row`">
            <div class="col-md-1" >MKB list</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Select MKB" class="ui-widget form-control autocomplete" name="f3" id="f3" value=""  data-href="{{URL::to('get1mkb10')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"><p id="id"></p></div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" value='submit' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>

        $( ".autocomplete" ).each(function(index, value){

            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).data('href'),
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {term:request.term},
                        success:function(data){
                            response($.map(data, function(item){
                                return { label: item.label, id: item.id}
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2,
                focus: function(event, ui){
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                    $(this).attr("value",ui.item.id);
                }
            });
        });


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show result of  console.log($(this).data('href') );

Comment: 09:41:29.1103 test:48 HREF: "http://lrvlauth/searchp"
09:41:29.118 test:48 HREF: "http://lrvlauth/searchr"
09:41:29.122 test:48 HREF: "http://lrvlauth/get1mkb10"
09:41:32.156 jquery.js:9566 XHR finished loading: GET "http://lrvlauth/test?term=ht".

Comment: In general AJAX returns correct data.  But autocomplete doesn't show the results. But if I change URL to static text it shows everything

Comment: try use {{ url('searchr') }}

Comment: same result. nothing changed

Answer (score -1):

try use

url: $(this).data('href')+"?t=" + (new Date()).getTime() //Add random number to prevent cache